# Searching inside an array in Flutter

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart

I have an array: List array
Each item of the array is another array: [String, DateTime, String]

So overall: array = [['abcd', 2020-05-27 00:00:00.000, 'fghi'],['jklm', 2020-05-23 00:00:00.000, 'nopqrs']]; etc etc

And I would like to search within the array using as a filter the DateTime and the second string, to get the value os the first String.

Search array where DateTime == something and secondString == something and return the correspondent first String.

I have no idea about how to do that... and I have been searching for a long long time.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

```
var array = [['abcd', DateTime.parse("2020-05-27 00:00:00.000"), 'fghi'],['jklm', DateTime.parse("2020-05-23 00:00:00.000"), 'nopqrs']];

// If you know there will be only one match
var foo = array.firstWhere((element) => element[1] == DateTime.parse("2020-05-23 00:00:00.000") && element[2] == 'nopqrs');
if(foo != null) {
  print(foo[0]);
}

// If you will have multiple matches
var bar = array.where((element) => element[1] == DateTime.parse("2020-05-23 00:00:00.000") && element[2] == 'nopqrs');
if(bar != null) {
  for(var b in bar){
    print(b[0]);
  }
}
```